# Why does this JavaScript statement begin with a ;

Tags: javascript

It's looks extraneous, but it must do something.

ref: https://github.com/quirkey/sammy/blob/master/examples/hello_world/index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    ;(function($) {
         //snip 
      });

      $(function() {
          //snip 
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the leading semicolon in JavaScript libraries do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873983/what-does-the-leading-semicolon-in-javascript-libraries-do) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145514/whats-the-purpose-of-starting-semi-colon-at-beginning-of-javascript

Comment: It's extraneous. Perhaps it makes it more copy-paste-able.

Comment: its actually useless in this example, but in standalone scripts it is used to prevent errors during concatenation due to semicolon insertion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to make sure previously loaded code that could have not been terminated with a semicolon gets terminated properly, otherwise it would result in an error. You could say it makes the code more tolerant to other people's bugs.

*Update*: I tested this out and at least in current Chrome and Firefox it makes no difference whether a previous statement is still open, so the semicolon has no effect on that. Idea: that might still be a problem with very old browsers, but I it is just an idea I didn't verify.

Comment: It doesn't have any purpose here when the script is inside the HTML document. Previous scripts don't affect this one. It's probably either copy-pasted from somewhere else or an oversight.

Comment: It has never been a problem in any browser. Ending expressions in semicolons has always been optional, and separate scripts have never interacted with each other this way. (The leading semicolon is only there to prevent possible problems when minifying or concatenating scripts with external tools.)

Comment: it depends on the context of the code before it. var t; t=22\n (function(){})(5) breaks without the "leading" semi...

Comment: @Juhana - no, its a problem with every browser; the opening paren resembles a function call, so if the last above expression leaked a result, the openeing paren would prevent semi-colon insertion and try to invoke the tail expression as a function.

Comment: @dandavis Good point -- but it's still a separate script and the previous script won't "leak" like that to the next one (otherwise you could do stuff like `<script>var a = "Hello </script><script>world";</script>`).