# what does the semikolon mean at the begining of this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what kind of code is that? what does the semikolon mean at the begining of this function?

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined )
```

what is the  purpose to write function like that?

```
creatorHashChanged: function(event) {}
```

what does "extend" mean here ?

```
$.extend( {}, defaults, options );
```

The complete code:

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

   function Plugin( options ) {
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this._tour = defaults.tour;

    if(this.options.delete) this.tourdate_delete(true);
    else this.init();
  }


  Plugin.prototype = {

    init: function() {

    },

    creatorHashChanged: function(event) {

    },

    exitCreator: function() {

    },


})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365172/semicolon-before-self-invoking-function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145514/

Comment: Regarding `$.extend`, have a look at the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is do the same function semicolon at the end.
I think it writed this way to prevent errors when script will be minimized.

> what is the purpose to write function like that?

To catch events

> what does "extend" mean here ?

Merge to object in one. Take a look at [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/).