# what do semi-colons at the start of a line do?

Tags: javascript

This comes from a project I downloaded to learn from:

```
;['delete', 'get', 'post', 'put', 'patch'].forEach((method) => {
    test(method, async () => {
      expect(global.fetch).not.toBeCalled()
      await api[method]('/foo')
      expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        'https://api.foo.com/foo',
        expect.objectContaining({ method })
      )
    })
  })
```

I've yet to see a line in js that starts with a semi-colon.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: It does nothing special (behaves like every other semicolon). In your case (without seeing more code) it does nothing

Comment: Is that all of the code? Usually, ';' are delimiters for the language parser.  I wonder if this delimits an unsee statement.  Otherwise, it's probably just delimiting nothing and being passed over by the language parser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365172/semicolon-before-self-invoking-function

Comment: if it is in a separate file which is included inside another file where you are including some more script files **before** this file then it might

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145514/whats-the-purpose-of-starting-semi-colon-at-beginning-of-javascript