# ; before document ready in jquery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the leading semicolon in JavaScript libraries do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873983/what-does-the-leading-semicolon-in-javascript-libraries-do)

I am reading the jquery flexslider source code and i see a `;` 
before the document ready call

```
;(function ($) {...
```

Can anyone tell me why we need a `;` ?

Comment: you don't need the `;`. It's probably a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's included in case...

- the code gets grouped into the same file with other code, and
- the other code didn't include a semicolon at the end.

---

For example...

```
    (function() {

       // some bundled plugin

    })()  // <--- no semicolon

//  v--- semicolon saved the day    
    ;(function ($) {

       // flexslider plugin

    })();
```

Without the semicolon, the `()` around the flexslider plugin would have been interpreted as a function call, and would have tried to call the return result of the previous function.

Answer (score 5):

This is just to protect against any previous code lines that might be missing a semicolon.

If you know that the code before has a semicolon at the end, this semicolon is not needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a typo. `;` prevents javascript errors in compliled/minified/compressed files. For example when several independent libraries/plugins get compressed together.