# Why is this defensive semicolon used?

Tags: javascript, lodash

In the [lodash library line](https://github.com/bestiejs/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L9), why is there a defensive semicolon on the first line?

```
;(function(window) {
    ...
}(this));
```

I recently read in Definitive JavaScript about defensive semicolons being used to protect against users who don't use semicolons properly, but as there is no preceding code, I don't see the point. Is this in case the library is concatenated on to the end of another library?

Comment: It is preferable to show the code as part of your question.

Comment: A simple YES is the answer to your question (at the end). :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the leading semicolon in JavaScript libraries do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873983/what-does-the-leading-semicolon-in-javascript-libraries-do)

Answer (score 6):

In case you use a javascript compressor/minifier, and the previous plugin does not have a `;` at the end, you might run into troubles. So, as a precaution, `;` is added.

Also, It safely allows you to append several javascript files, to serve it in a single `HTTP` request.

Answer (score 1):

That semicolon is also used to ensure that it is not interpreted as a continuation of the previous statement:

```
var x = 0 // Semicolon omitted here
;[x,x+1,x+2].forEach(console.log) // Defensive ; keeps this statement separate
```

More detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20854706/1048668