# What is the point of using empty statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I tried to search for good resources on empty statement, but it seem like nothing show up. Even on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty), they don't have much to say about it.

i.e:

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; a[i++] = 0);

if((a==0) || (b == 0));
```

I would like to know what are some real examples that one should use empty statements on their project. What are the reason behind it?

Comment: let me quote from the code comment just above the for loop: `// Assign all array values to 0`

Comment: It is helpful for [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com). For example this saves 2 bytes because you don't need a code block wrapped in brackets `{}`: `for(a=0;a++<100;b=a,c=b+a);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples you've given don't make much sense. They should better be written

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length;) a[i++] = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) a[i] = 0;
; // the comparisons really don't do anything (assuming a and b are no objects)
(a==0) || (b = 0); // Oh wait, that's the one given by @Shomz
if (a != 0) b = 0;
```

However, there are real-world applications for the empty statement. I'll just list 3 that come to my mind:

- ```
  function x() {
      …
  };
  ```

  A semicolon where it doesn't belong (e.g. after the function declaration above) makes an empty statement.
- ```
  ;
  …
  ```

  A [leading semicolon on your script files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1873983/1048572) helps to guard against buggy inclusions or file concatenations.
- ```
  while (!check_for_finish()); // do nothing
  ```

  An empty loop body can be used for busy-waiting loops (not recommended) and similar.

Answer (score 2):

none/lazyness. there is absolutely no difference to

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length;) a[i++] = 0;
```

and just a minimal difference to

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) a[i] = 0;
```

the first one is a few ms faster after a few billion iteration steps; aka. premature optimization

**EDIT:**

```
if((a==0) || (b == 0));
```

this makes no sense at all, since it does nothing.

but expresions like

```
a==0 || (b=0);

//or maybe sth like this:

//var noop = ()=>void 0;  //FYI

typeof a === "function" || (a = noop);
```

are pretty useful to me, since they are short, and readable and an additional if-statement doesn't add any value to readability or understanding (at least once you know this pattern).

Comment: Have you tested it? I'm pretty sure it is *not* faster.

Comment: yeah, it's because in `a[i++]=0` i++ (increment and getting the value of i) are processed as one instruction, whilst in `a[i]=0; i++;` they are two; but as i said, premature optimizations. Every function-call or deoptimized function, and so much more has a way higher impact on performance than this optimization.

Comment: What "instruction" do you mean? You cannot just count JS tokens.

Answer (score 1):

The first one obviously loops through the array and assigns all values to zero, without having the code specified in the statement.

The other one seems like a typo, because it is useless.

However, something like

```
if((a==0) || (b = 0));
```

would make sense, as it would assign `b` to zero in case `a` is not zero.

```js
var a = 1, b = 1;
if((a == 0) || (b = 0));

alert("a: " + a + ", b: " + b);
```

Comment: you have strange definition of `make sense` - `if(a===0) b=0;` or even `b = (a===0 ? 0 : b)` are both more readable IMO

Comment: Obviously not a recommended practice nor something I'd suggest nor something that I'd write, but **an answer to the question**. There are assignments in conditionals, probably more than you'd expect to see. Coming up with more readable variations would be irrelevant and exhausting here. Focus on the question.

Comment: please allow me to add an emphasis to the OP's question: "real examples that one **should** use empty statements"

Comment: Sorry, I either missed that part, or it was edited while I was writing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that they are really useful, but I can be wrong.
One can try to use side effects of the evaluation of the conditions in an if, but I do not see a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite use for it is to wait for a condition to become true.

```
while ( !condition );
// do what happens once your condition is met
```

This is nice to read, in my opinion, but the same can be done with `{ }` instead of the empty statement.

Answer (score 0):

The first example `for(var i = 0; i < a.length; a[i++] = 0);` is useful IMO, and the reasons would be:

- Writing less without sacrificing readability.
- beauty!
- Telling people: Hey, I'm a pro JS coder. :)

The second one `if((a==0) || (b == 0));` seems doesn't nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose you have two functions `X` and `Y` and let us suppose that `Y` must only be executed when `X` returns `true`, in such a situation you will write:

```
if( X() && Y() );
```

Comment: No. You would write `if (X()) Y();` (or `X() && Y();`). No empty statement.

Comment: Why not `X() && Y()`?