# Self-invoking JS function

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

I have the following code:

```
        var currentKey = 0;
        var totalBinaryMultiplesCollection = {};
        for (var row in playField) {
            if (playField.hasOwnProperty(row)) {
                alert(row + " -> " + playField[row]);
                var rowLength = playField[row].length;
                //Call rowCalc function which returns an array with the binary nrs used in calc
                var binaryMultiplesRow = rowCalc(rowLength);
                for(j=0; j < binaryMultiplesRow.length; j++){
                    //Two methods
                    totalBinaryMultiplesCollection[currentKey] = binaryMultiplesRow[j];
                    currentKey+=1;
                }
            }   
        }
```

I want to change this code to be a self-invoking function. So I added the following things:
`(function (){`  before the code block.
`})();`   behind the code block.
This however gives me the following error: 
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...) is not a function(…). 
I can't seem to find the problem here. Could someone tell me what is going on?
Current version:

```
(function () {
        var currentKey = 0;
        var totalBinaryMultiplesCollection = {};
        for (var row in playField) {
            if (playField.hasOwnProperty(row)) {
                alert(row + " -> " + playField[row]);
                var rowLength = playField[row].length;
                //Call rowCalc function which returns an array with the binary nrs used in calc
                var binaryMultiplesRow = rowCalc(rowLength);
                for(j=0; j < binaryMultiplesRow.length; j++){
                    //Two methods
                    totalBinaryMultiplesCollection[currentKey] = binaryMultiplesRow[j];
                    currentKey+=1;
                }
            }   
        }
    })();
```

and the rowCalc function being called:

```
var rowCalc = function(rowlength){
        var currentRowCollection = [];
        switch(rowlength) {
        case 1:
            currentRowCollection.push(1);
            break;
        case 2:
            currentRowCollection.push(2);
            break;
        case 3:
            currentRowCollection.push(1);
            currentRowCollection.push(2);
            break;
        case 4:
            currentRowCollection.push(4);
            break;
        case 5:
            currentRowCollection.push(1);
            currentRowCollection.push(4);
            break;
        case 6:
            currentRowCollection.push(2);
            currentRowCollection.push(4);
        case 7:
            currentRowCollection.push(2);
            currentRowCollection.push(4);
            currentRowCollection.push(1);
            break;
        default:
            alert("You made a mistake!")
        }
        return currentRowCollection; 
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the version that is giving you errors?

Comment: Hey Rob, edited!  :)

Comment: There seems to be a missing semicolon on the previous line.

Comment: Try changing it to `;(function(){…}());` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1873983/1048572))

Comment: `rowCalc` definition needs to end with a semicolon, as does the `alert` within it (probably less important)

Comment: I added both the semicolons (at the end of the rowCalc function and before the self-invoking function). It works now :) Thnx!

Comment: @Kai: Using a `!` or some other unary operator is nicer than using `()` for these "self invoking" functions. `!function() { ... }()`. Totally eliminates the possibility of a missing semicolon causing the parens (or any binary or postfix operator) to be interpreted differently from what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

There are two missing semicolons in your `rowCalc` function, the second of which is causing the error:

```
var rowCalc = function(rowlength){
    var currentRowCollection = [];
    switch(rowlength) {
    case 1:
        currentRowCollection.push(1);
        break;
    case 2:
        currentRowCollection.push(2);
        break;
    case 3:
        currentRowCollection.push(1);
        currentRowCollection.push(2);
        break;
    case 4:
        currentRowCollection.push(4);
        break;
    case 5:
        currentRowCollection.push(1);
        currentRowCollection.push(4);
        break;
    case 6:
        currentRowCollection.push(2);
        currentRowCollection.push(4);
    case 7:
        currentRowCollection.push(2);
        currentRowCollection.push(4);
        currentRowCollection.push(1);
        break;
    default:
        alert("You made a mistake!");
//                                  ^
    }
    return currentRowCollection; 
}; /*
 ^  */
```