# jQuery on HTML page not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm no jQuery guru, and cannot seem to get this *needed* jQuery feature loaded on a site for a client.  I've double-checked that all files paths are correct - and they are - but nothing seems to be working.

I've hosted the site live - you can check the source on there.  (SOURCE CODE REMOVED)   A map should be appearing between the nav and footer - but nothing!

Comment: Why are you including two (different) versions of jQuery on the same page? Check your browser's console for errors.

Comment: Also - *SyntaxError: missing } after function body* - The console. Remember, the console is your friend.

Comment: Don't mix 2 versions of jQuery librarys.. these will conflict with each other. But there is nothing to say it is not possible, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: Your inline code starts like this:  `<script>
    ;(function ...` What is the leading semi-colon for? And, the console reports an error on the last line of your code, indicating that some syntax is not matched up.

Comment: @ScottMarcus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873983/what-does-the-leading-semicolon-in-javascript-libraries-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened your website link and I saw on [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) you are missing a braces somewhere:

[image]

I strongly recommend you to use some developer tool like Firebug to see the Javascript errors. Try to find your issue and let me know if it will work.

Comment: Chrome's console is probably the better choice.

Comment: personally I love Firebug haha

Comment: Firebug is okay, I started on firebug. Chrome's console just gives a more in-depth and informative error message. Not to mention, it's device mimic ability.

Comment: Thanks, that was all that was needed!  
I don't use Javascript or jQuery, debugging a language you barely know is a hassle even with dev tools.

Note to self: learn javascript

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>` line as you're already using the minified version.

You have 2 versions of jQuery being used in your site right now:

`jQuery v1.11.1` and `jQuery v2.1.4`.

Decide which one you want to use and remove the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check when your scripts are being fired. Jquery usually works best when loaded early on before any other scripts on your page.

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Javascript console, you will see you have an error in your Javascript syntax:

[image]

It seems you forgot to close a parenthesis.
Probably because this line:

```
$("#image-map-pro-container").imageMapPro({"id":3082,"edi ...
```

is too long, I'd suggest you try to break it into pieces.