# ;(function() {})(); in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, file

I am looking at a JavaScript file, and it is formatted as follows:

```
;(function() {

    // functions and stuff

})();
```

What does this mean, and what is this 'technique' called?

Comment: clossure function.... commonly using to reduce the scope

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript

Comment: I think everyone missed the fact that your example starts with a semicolon. This answer explains why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1873999/1395510

Answer (score 1):

[Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Answer (score 1):

Its called Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions (IIFEs) like

```
// variant 1

(function () {
  alert('Woohoo!');
})();

// variant 2

(function () {
  alert('Woohoo!');
}());
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-closures-callbacks-iifes/)

Answer (score 0):

This is an anonymous self-executing function.

I would refer you to these resources as of why:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions
http://esbueno.noahstokes.com/post/77292606977/self-executing-anonymous-functions-or-how-to-write