# ESLint - Start file with a semicolon

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am building a linter, in order to have consistency between the team, for our legacy codebase which is vanilla JS with a file combiner (concatenates all JS files into one).

I want all javascript files to start with a semicolon. If you want to know the reason, check this: [What does the leading semicolon in JavaScript libraries do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873983/what-does-the-leading-semicolon-in-javascript-libraries-do). Do you know any plugin that ensures semicolon at the beginning of a file?

I also want to keep `no-extra-semi` option from `eslint:recommended`, any suggestions about how to do it?

Comment: Your *bundler* (I think thats what you are calling a "file combiner") should already create a valid bundle and there should be no need to manually add (unnecessary) semicolons somewhere.

Comment: Our bundler just combines files nothing smart, that's why I called it combiner. I think semicolons in the beginning of file is a good practice that's why I need it.

Comment: @JonasWilms I've worked with some in-house bundler that didn't. And that wasn't the only issue with it, either. It was...rather unpleasant. Basically, you're saying "[bunblder] should" but that's not necessarily the case. I do understand that's not an argument to keep it - it's actually an argument to ditch it (one I couldn't win back then) but it might explain where OP is coming from.

Comment: @laltin ah, sounds like the in-house monstrosity I dealt with. It would do a glorified copy/past of the contents of the file through a rather convoluted means...

Comment: @VLAZ not exactly in-house thing, actually it is a framework. in the worst case I will create my own plugin for that