# what is semicolon before square bracket?

Tags: javascript

I looked at someone's code and found this line,

```
;[result] = await session.onWhatsApp(jid)
```

what is the meaning of using a semicolon before a square bracket?

what is the different between this:

```
[result] = await session.onWhatsApp(jid)
```

and this:

```
;[result] = await session.onWhatsApp(jid)
```

[image]

Comment: It's there to prevent problems that might carry over from the previous line of code thanks to JavaScript automatic semicolon insertion rules.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873983/what-does-the-leading-semicolon-in-javascript-libraries-do